# Fastest implementation of lead() or lag() window functions in MonetDB

Tags: sql, performance, window-functions, monetdb, sqlperformance

I was really surprised MonetDB, an analytical column-based DB doesn't have analytical functions like lead() or lag(). I really need them to calculate time between user events. The tables are large (more than a billion of rows) and I don't want to perform self-join.

Is there any way to emulate fast lead() or lag() window functions in MonetDB?

Comment: Could it be user defined functions? If so, how fast it will be?

Answer (score 1):

Both operators assume knowledge about the row order in your table. In general, a relational system is free to dis-obey the insertion/update order. That's why it is not directly supported.

If you know on what column(s) you would like to implement the lead/lag then a UDF is indeed the way to go. This could even be developed in R or Python.
regards, Martin